# SceneKit - Crossfade material property textures

Tags: opengl-es, core-animation, scenekit

The documentation for [`SCNMaterialProperty.contents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contents) states that it is an animatable property and indeed I can perform a crossfade between two colors. However I’m unable to crossfade between two images.

So I’m starting to wonder if this is possible at all or if I need to create a custom shader for this?

---

I’ve tried an implicit animation, in which case it immediately shows the ‘after’ image:

```
node.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"before"];
[SCNTransaction begin];
[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
node.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"after"];
[SCNTransaction commit];
```

An explicit animation, which does nothing:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"before"].CGImage;
animation.toValue = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"after"].CGImage;
animation.duration = 5;
[node.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

---

As well as through a `CALayer`, which does nothing:

```
CALayer *textureLayer = [CALayer layer];
textureLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 793, 1006);
textureLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"before"].CGImage;
node.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = textureLayer;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"before"].CGImage;
animation.toValue = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"after"].CGImage;
animation.duration = 5;
[textureLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried animating a change between two materials, instead of between two contents values for the same material property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my own testing, it doesn't look like this property is actually animatable when texture values are involved (rather than solid color values). Either that's a bug in SceneKit (i.e. it's intended to be animatable but that's not working) or it's a bug in Apple's docs (i.e. it's not intended to be animatable but they say it is). Either way, you should [file that bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) so you get notified when Apple fixes it.

(It also doesn't look like this is a tvOS-specific issue -- I see it on OS X as well.)

I can understand why animated texture transitions might not be there... from a GL/Metal perspective, that requires binding an extra texture unit and having two texture lookups per pixel (instead of one) during the transition.

I can think of a couple of decent potential workarounds:

1. Use a shader modifier. Write a GLSL(ish) snippet that looks something like this:

   ```
   uniform sampler2D otherTexture;
   uniform float fadeFactor;
   #pragma body
   vec4 otherTexel = texture2D(otherTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord);
   _surface.diffuse = mix(_surface.diffuse, otherTexel, fadeFactor);
   ```

   Set it on the material you want to animate using the `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface` entry point. Then use `setValue:forKey:` to associate a `SCNMaterialProperty` with the `otherTexture` and a `CABasicAnimation` to animate the `fadeFactor` from 0 to 1.
2. Use something more animated (like a SpriteKit scene) as your material property contents, and animate that to perform the transition. (As a bonus, when you do it this way, you can use other transition styles.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly! I had tried to bind a texture before through KVC, but I mistakingly assigned the image directly without the use of `SCNMaterialProperty`, which seems silly in retrospect. I’ll file that Radar right away.

Comment: Hello @rickster, can you please give an example on how to apply CABasicAnimation for fadeFactor ? I try many things, but that doesn't work !!! Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your animation isn't happening because "contents" property is animatable only when set to a color not for image. You can read it on the apple's documentation about contents property.

Comment: I just took another look at the docs, but I can’t find anything about an image not being suitable for animating.

Comment: From the Documentation: 
     property contents:
     Specifies the receiver's contents. This can be a color (NSColor/UIColor), an image (NSImage/CGImageRef), a layer (CALayer), a path (NSString or NSURL), a SpriteKit scene (SKScene) or a texture (SKTexture, id<MTLTexture> or GLKTextureInfo). Animatable when set to a color.

Comment: Huh, even when I do a search for “Animatable when set to a color” I can’t find it on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contents. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: I see. I don’t use Xcode, so I was referring to the online doc that I linked to, weird that they’d diverge.

Comment: If the current content is a solid color, you can use explicit or implicit animations (see Animating SceneKit Content) to change to another color, creating an effect that fades between the two colors. Using animations to change from or to other content types results in an instantaneous transition—for an animated transition between textured content types (or types that are themselves animated), create a shader modifier (see SCNShadable).