# Animate shader value

Tags: ios, swift, animation, glsl, scenekit

With a solution give by **@rickster** in this post : [SceneKit - Crossfade material property textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235058/scenekit-crossfade-material-property-textures), I try to implement an animation on **fadeFactor**. I try many things but nothing works as expected.

Here is some of my code :

- For shader :

  `"uniform float fadeFactor;"`
- In swift :

  ```
  let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fadeFactor")
  anim.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0)
  anim.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1.0)
  anim.duration = duration
  anim.repeatCount = .infinity
  node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "fadeFactor")
  ```

When I execute my code, no animation on **fadeFactor** property.
What I'm doing wrong ?
In CABasicAnimation, I try different values for **keyPath** : geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents, fadeFactor, etc.
I can't find which value I must give for parameters **'keyPath'** and **'forKey'** !

When I change value for **fadeFactor** with **setValue** function, it's OK :

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.setValue(NSNumber(value: 0.5), forKey: "fadeFactor")
```

If somenone have a solution or can give me an example, it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, finally that's work after make a clean of the project !!!
**Project -> Clean Build Folder**